# jQuery json for loop getting each char instead of item array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have got script like that:

```
$.getJSON("someurl", function(data){
    for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
});
```

and json array looks like:

```
[1,2]
```

but this script is getting each char of this json response, so in console I am getting:

```
[ index:44
1 index:44
, index:44
2 index:44
] index:44
```

What am I doing wrong with it?

Comment: it looks like a string to me.... can you add a `console.log(typeof data)` before the `for` loop

Comment: Also what is the content type of the respose

Comment: is the response double-encoded? Because jQuery should parse the response for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `json` string is looking like string not `array`

```
$.getJSON("someurl", function(data){
    data=$.parseJSON(data);
    for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
});
```

Read [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parseJSON/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsTkQ/1/)